# What LCD protector should I get for a Nikon D5100?

Tags: nikon, equipment-protection, lcd, rear-lcd

Just bought my wife the D5100 as a gift and I was looking for recommendations for a LCD screen protector.  The articulating screen was part of the reason I got the camera, but it obviously limits the options of screen protectors given the space constraints.

I have the Zagg product on my iPhone, and I'm a big fan (given that I beat the crap out of my phone).  However, I'm concerned it is too shiny for this application.

Comment: Zagg is fine.  They are a bit expensive.  I usually just grab the cheapies from either Amazon or Newegg, order them bigger then the application, and cut to size. Some people like glossy, some like matte, some like ultra clear, etc - just try the cheap ones and see what you like.

Answer (score 3):

Many lcd screens, including those on some dSLR cameras already have a "protective screen." Basically the part that you see on the outside and can touch is a hard cover that is non-permanently glued on.

Some Nikon models like D3/D700/D300 have tempered glass over the display so chances are you won't nick it easily.

The screen on my camera costs like <15 bucks shipped from Canon, and can be removed with a suction cup and a blowdryer if it is scratched too much.

A "nice" glass one from Giotto's Aegis or something cost more than double that, and introduces two more reflective layers of glass. Of course then they go on touting antireflective coatings on the screen protector for your screen protector...

What I'm saying is to find out by contacting Nikon if your D5100's screen protector is equally removable and low cost to replace or if it's made of glass.

Comment: I don't believe the D5100 comes with a screen protector of any description. At least, the screen seemed fragile when I looked at one. (That's actually the main reason I went to the D7000 instead of the D5100 -- I think I would break the 5100's screen)

Comment: Having played with a friend's D5100 a bit, I'm also scared by that flip screen, but find myself pining for it on some shots, like when I don't feel like getting my face in the dirt.