# How to protect my camera's rear lcd?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, equipment-protection, rear-lcd

I searched a bit and found two main types of protections: [plastic](http://www.amazon.co.uk/EASYi-Screen-Protector-Digital-Camera/dp/B001A3PY6Q/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1314019777&sr=1-1) and [glass](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Optical-Glass-Screen-Protector-Nikon/dp/B004P7B2GK/ref=sr_1_1?s=electronics&ie=UTF8&qid=1314019789&sr=1-1). Plastic is a lot cheaper but a lot of people complain about bubbles, dust, and low adherence. The glass ones [seem to be better](http://www.digitalhomethoughts.com/news/show/99790/1/1/2) but are more expensive.

Which one do you advise? Do you use any of these solutions?
My biggest concern is the "glue" residues that eventually some of them might leave.

Comment: See also http://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/14355/what-lcd-protector-should-i-get-for-a-nikon-d5100

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used both [glass](http://www.bhphotovideo.com/c/product/571435-REG/Giottos_SP8306_SP8306_AEGIS_Professional_Glass.html) and [plastic](http://www.bestskinsever.com/other-stuff/cameras). Giottos (glass) and BestSkinsEver (plastic).  Bottomline, the glass is by far the best looking in terms of optical quality. Glare is the same as the LCD itself.  However, it is relatively expensive, and the tape that is used is just around the outside, so if it is not done properly or evenly, dust will get in.  Being glass, it will scratch, but at least it is disposable. But scratches on a $30 cover can make you just as angry.

FWIW, the LCD already has a protective glass cover that is replaceable. However, I do not think it is replaceable by consumers, and must be sent to your camera maker. Just know that there is already glass covering the LCD.

The plastic does not have the same clarity, but unless you are pixel peeping on the LCD, you won't notice. Glare is gone completely. The clarity depends on the care with which it is applied: it must be very clean and smoothed over well.  The plastic does not scratch, and at [around $6](http://www.bestskinsever.com/other-stuff/cameras), its easy to replace. The 'glue' is over the whole surface though some use attach via static or hydrostatic methods (no glue). I have the plastic on my smartphone, iPad and 40D LCD and have been happy. It removes easily, though you can not reuse the plastic if you remove it, as it stretches in removing it.

My recommendation: get the plastic, give it a try. If you hate the clarity, go for the glass.

Comment: Many of the glass ones (including the one he linked) are more in th e 6-10 dollar range.

Comment: @rfusca: yes, thanks I saw that. However, I have not tried that one, I have tried the Giottos I linked to. Perhaps the OP can then try the Amazon model risk free given the price.

Comment: On Canons at least, the built-in screen protector is user-replaceable. And a replacement one costs rather less than a good screen protector protector does, so I frankly don't see what the fuss is about.

Comment: That's great! Does anyone knows how it works with Nikon?

Comment: @DiAlex - if you're referring to the D3100, given your other question, its not a user replaceable part.  You'd need a glass or plastic piece to protect.

Comment: Note that 'user replaceable' means that if you are willing to follow instructions of others who have done it, and purchase parts, of unknown quality from ebay, then yes,it is possible. Canon does not make parts available nor a 'kit' for users. Google around a bit, and you will find videos of folks using suction cups etc to remove them.

Comment: @cmason: Sure they do. The protector has a part number, go to a photo shop and order that part. (The difficult bit is to find the number.) It is not something they stock. The new screen protector has double-sided tape already in place. Rocket science it ain't. You have to provide your own suction cup though.

Answer (score 1):

I have used the "Invisible Shield" products for my cameras for years. All 4 of my current cameras are protected by them along with my iPhones and iPods. I am currently unhappy with their customer service but the shields themselves have really worked as advertised for me.

I chose to use the sticker option instead of having an additional bit of glass or plastic hanging off the back of my camera that might get caught on something or get in the way of me looking through the eyepiece.

Of the 10 or so devices I have used the invisible Shield on I have not had a single scratch and they have come off cleanly for resale.

Comment: I also thought of "Invisible Shield" but I couldn't find any product for digital cameras. «Resale»? You can take them off and they are still good to a resale? Too awesome? :P

Comment: On their web site you can choose "digital cameras" and then make and model. http://www.zagg.com/invisibleshield/index.php

Answer (score 1):

I used the plastic cover supplied with my Nikon D90 when I first bought it, but a grain of grit got stuck behind it and actually caused a scratch on my screen.

Since then, I've been using a rebranded 3M screen protection film and it's much better.  There's a knack to it but once you've figured it out you can put it on without any bubbles.  I've removed them in the past from the screen of phones when they've been scratched and they don't leave residue.  It doesn't protect against a physical impact though.

Comment: I use the plastic cover too, in fact I've rarely taken it off.